# Is there a KiCad library loader for Linux?

Tags: pcb, kicad, library

I have been using Designspark PCB with [Library loader](https://www.samacsys.com/library-loader/) for years now. Library loader lets me import and use any footprint instantly once I download it.

But I want to switch to Linux with KiCad, and I want an alternative for Library loader, since I do not want to manually replace my files for footprints; I would love it to be automatic.

Even if there is a plugin it would help.

**EDIT:**

Regarding the plugin: The closest thing I could achieve was to use [SnapEda's Kicad Plugin](https://www.snapeda.com/plugins/), but it looks like it only works on Windows. Trying to use it in Linux (Ubuntu) after installing `sudo apt-get install python3-tk`, which is needed, I ended up with a gray screen of the plugin saying Nothing (it is supposedly installing but it just freezes there)

[image]